# Vpn for communication with instances on google cloud platform

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-platform, vpn-client

I was in another part of the community, asking about how to create a vpn using instances in GCP, they told me that I had to add the vpn service in one instance, I am doing the test with a windows 2012 r2 server, already configure the vpn service and check That the ports were open to be able to access, and outside of the instance also create a route and my firewall rules to be able to allow access, I want to connect from a windows client but it does not allow me to do so, I leave images, rules and routes below , I hope they can guide me, I have read the document but I have done what they ask me there and I can not make it work.

[My routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaMId.png)
[My rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29eW7.png)

Comment: I already edit it

Comment: Hello, I already moved the publication to this section @nwarriorch

Comment: Hello, your images with the routes and firewall rules are no longer available on the provided links. Did you resolve your issue? It would be good if you share your answer. In case if you are still experiencing the issue, can you reattach the rules and the routes?